# Cos'è una "passerella kapok"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Un’intera divisione ammutolita nel silenzio piú assoluto, pronta a muoversi senza copertura d’artiglieria, perché l’effetto sorpresa non venga rovinato. Migliaia di uomini pressati in 45 navi d’assalto, cariche di **passerelle kapok**, zattere, pontoni e materiale per lanciare un ponte Bailey sul fiume. La riva una riga piatta, buia. I Royal Scots Fusiliers sbarcheranno due chilometri al di là delle linee tedesche, a monte della foce del Garigliano.

Sul [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/K/kapok.html) ho trovato che "kapok", scritto anche "capoc" o "capok", significa

> Materiale costituito dalla lanugine interna dei frutti di alcune piante bombacacee tropicali, usato per imbottiture

e una definizione un po' più dettagliata si trova sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capoc):

> Bambagia di colore dal bianco giallognolo al grigio, a lucentezza serica, costituita dai peli lanosi che rivestono internamente la parete del frutto (capsula) di varî alberi tropicali appartenenti alla famiglia delle bombacacee, fra i quali il più importante è *Eriodendron anfractuosum*, particolarm. coltivato nella regione indomalese; è un materiale soffice usato per imbottire materassi, cuscini, ecc. *Olio di c.*, olio di colore dal giallo chiaro al bruno, ricavato per spremitura a caldo dalla farina dei semi degli stessi frutti; si usa come olio commestibile, in miscela con altri olî, e nella preparazione di saponi

Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è una "passerella kapok"? Ne ho trovato una fotografia sul [sito web della biblioteca digitale dell'Istituto per la Storia e le Memorie del '900 Parri Emilia-Romagna](http://parridigit.istitutoparri.eu/fondi.aspx?key=dettaglio&fondo=11&rec_id=6917&from=ricerca&cp=177).

Comment: Cos’è una passerella Kapok è evidente dall’ultimo link che hai fornito. La domanda è:  perché si chiama  Kapok.

Comment: [Questo](https://www.travelwiththewind.org/foresta-amazzonica-peruviana/) è un sito di chissacchì, ma forse ci dà un indizio: parla di “Osservazione della fauna amazzonica dal Canopy (una passerella sospesa su un kapok -> cotton tree) da cui è possibile vedere scimmie e uccelli di ogni specie e colori”. Quindi c'è la possibilità che la “passerella kapok” sia una “passerella simile a quelle sospese agli alberi del kapok”.

Comment: Vedi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontoon_bridge e https://www.thinkdefence.co.uk/2011/12/uk-military-bridging-floating-equipment/kapok-infantry-bridge/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secondo https://www.thinkdefence.co.uk/2011/12/uk-military-bridging-floating-equipment/kapok-infantry-bridge/ un ponte kapok è un ponte militare con una passerella appoggiata a pontoni galleggianti riempiti di kapok (la lanugine simile al cotone di cui si parla nei dizionari citati). L'imbottitura permette il galleggiamento anche se i pontoni sono colpiti dal fuoco nemico.

[image]

Sorgente https://u0v052dm9wl3gxo0y3lx0u44wz-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Kapok-Infantry-Bridge.jpg